# defrag command line in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, command-line, defragment, safe-mode

I'm trying to consolidate my system partition volume by running defrag in a command prompt in command line recovery mode.

This is the command I'm trying to have executed: `defrag C: /X /H /U`

After I enter the command above all I can see is:

```
Microsoft Disk Defragmenter
Copyright (c) 2007 Microsoft Corp.
```

and the line is ready to take new commands.
No reports, no time used to execute the operation.

Am I doing something wrong? Is the operation executing in the background?

Comment: Run the following command and post here the full output: `wmic logicaldisk get caption,filesystem,size,volumename`

Comment: here you are: `Caption  FileSystem  Size          VolumeName  
C:       NTFS        100075040768  OS          
D:       NTFS        216149475328              
E:                                             
`

Comment: Judging by the output: `C:` is 93 GiB and it's associated with the operating system; `D:` is 201 GiB and is probably used to store personal data; `E:` should correspond to a CD/DVD drive. Correct if I'm wrong. Which steps did you follow to run the `defrag` utility, exactly? Do you get the same issue if you try `defrag D: /X /H /U` instead?

Comment: You're right about the data given by logicaldisk, the machine also has a FAT recovery partition and ext4+swap partitions.

Comment: The steps I took are to enter Windows in safe made and then input the command in a prompt. I tried to do this in command prompt recovery mode (no gui), in "normal" recovery mode (in this case I did elevate the prompt) and in a normal session. In the normal session the command executes without any problem, in recovery mode it just gives the copyright info and no other output.

Comment: I'm trying to execute the command in recovery mode because I'm trying a few steps suggested in some gparted documentation about shrinking Windows partitions without making a whole mess out of it (at this point I have the file $mftmirr written at the very end of those 93GB).

Comment: It seems like `defrag *` is not loaded in recovery mode...

Comment: It works for me: http://i.stack.imgur.com/3PKsE.png

Comment: are you using a version of Windows 7 without the SP1 updates?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16189/discussion-between-and31415-and-maja).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

atm, that's the answer:

[Is Disk Defragmenter disabled by default in Windows 7 Safe mode?](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/71b1d715-4dff-4a73-a435-0969994d6bca/is-disk-defragmenter-disabled-by-default-in-windows-7-safe-mode?forum=w7itproperf)

[Why is Disk Defragmenter disabled by default in Safe mode in Windows 7?](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/861c5c61-bca7-4266-9f82-28d88a846b62/why-is-disk-defragmenter-disabled-by-default-in-safe-mode-in-windows-7?forum=w7itproperf)

Comment: also, if someone would change the question into "defrag command line in Windows 7's recovery mode" the whole post would make more sense..